# kafka-connect-elasticsearch: storing messages as format of predefined index

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka

Example:

```
{"id":"1","firstName":"abc","lastName":"xyz","dob":"12/09/1995","age":"23"}
```

This message structure is in kafka topic, but i want to index this in elasticsearch as below

```
{"id":"1","name"{"firstName":"abc","lastName":"xyz"},"dob":"12/09/1995","age":"23"}
```

how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Stream processing against the data in the Kafka topic. Using Kafka Streams you could wrangle the data model as required. KSQL would work for this in inverse but doesn't support *creating* STRUCTs yet. Other stream processing options would be Flink, Spark Streaming, etc
2. Modify the data as it passes through Kafka Connect, using Single Message Transform. There's no pre-built transform that does this but you could write one using [the API](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Transformation.html).

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent, the company behind the open-source KSQL project, constributes to Kafka Streams, Kafka Connect, etc.*